# How to group data frame according date and sort values in descending order

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, group-by

I am new to stack overflow and asked a question before that wasn't much informative. I want to ask a question that is more detailed this time.

So, I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
test_ret_stacked.rename(columns={'ret_applied':'ret'},inplace=True);test_ret_stacked
```

[This is how my test_re_stacked data frame looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbbJt.png)

I am not too sure how to upload iPynb output to stackoverflow...

With the data frame above, I tried to do:

```
test_ret_stacked.groupby(test_ret_stacked[test_ret_stacked['date','ticker']]).sort_values(by = 'ret' ascending=False)
```

but it won't work, even if I do just:

```
test_ret_stacked.groupby(test_ret_stacked[test_ret_stacked['date','ticker']])
```

I am new to coding and I am not really sure if I delivered what I want to do here, but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your post ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.